# Rename only specific columns in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to rename specific columns in R data frame.

```
asd <- data.frame(asdds = c(1,2), sfrfr = c(3,4), dsfsg = c(4,5))
asd
  asdds sfrfr dsfsg
1     1     3     4
2     2     4     5

colnames(asd[1]) <- c(substring(names(asd[1]), 4))
```

I am trying to replace first columns with its substring

Expected output

```
asd
      ds sfrfr dsfsg
1     1     3     4
2     2     4     5
```

Answer (score 4):

The syntax is :

```
colnames(asd)[1] <- substring(names(asd[1]), 4)
asd

#  ds sfrfr dsfsg
#1  1     3     4
#2  2     4     5
```

`colnames(asd[1])` is a subset of dataframe, you can't rename a subset of dataframe. `colnames(asd)[1]` is subset of column names.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `rename_at`

```
library(dplyr)
asd <-  asd %>% 
    rename_at(1,  ~ substring(., 4))
asd
#   ds sfrfr dsfsg
#1  1     3     4
#2  2     4     5
```